# how to, javascript Pop Under not popping in the background

Tags: javascript

i have this simple script of a popunder window:

```
function loadpopunder(){
win2=window.open(popunder,"",winfeatures)
win2.blur()
window.focus()
}
```

It works but it looks like the new window doesn't load under the main one. it loads on top.

i've been looking at this from multiple ways and i can't figure it out.

any ideas?

thanks

edit: this code is just a sample, mine actually has all the `;` and the http://.. link,

also, i understand that none likes the popunders, i don't like them either, is just one of those things that needs to be done. I hope one day someone will figure a way of blocking those too, but i am here bcause i am looking for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please reconsider your choice. There are about zero people that enjoy pop-unders.**

For the sake of answering your question, here is what's considered a better way: http://icant.co.uk/articles/how-to-create-popunders/