# Opening an inactive tab in a browser using jQuery

Tags: jquery, window, href

How would you open a new inactive tab in a browser using jQuery, such as using Ctrl+click?

Comment: you can't control that? `window.open(url)` or `<a href='url' target='_blank'>...</a>`

Comment: What if the browser doesn't support tabs?  Or has tabs set to behave differently than you expect?  Don't try to short-circuit browser functionality with your JavaScript.  Just open the URL (either in the current target or a new target), let the user/browser decide what to do with it.

Comment: I want to open link in background tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272937/how-to-javascript-pop-under-not-popping-in-the-background

Comment: I find solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386208/open-a-new-browser-tab-in-background-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javacript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a:not([@href*=])").not("[href^=#]")
        .addClass("external")
        .attr({ target: "_blank" });
    }
);
</script>
```

see if this helps